# How can I hide an element with A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

What is the best way to hide an element using A-Frame?

Do I need to remove the element from the DOM?

Answer (score 10):

```
var el = document.querySelector("#yourElementId");

el.setAttribute("visible",false);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to hide an element is the `visible` attribute:

`myElement.setAttribute("visible", false)`

Comment: Hi. Do you mean myElement.setAttribute('visible', false); ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify it on the a-frame tag itself e.g.:

```
<a-image id="hand-overview-chart"
  src="#handOverviewImg" position="3 3 0"
  width="4" height="4" visible="false">
</a-image>
```

Of course you'll still need javascript to trap on some event like "mouseenter" to toggle it visible:

```
document.querySelector('#myElParentId').addEventListener('mouseenter',myEventHandler); 

myEventHandler: function (evt) {
  let myEl = document.querySelector("#hand-overview-chart");
  myEl.setAttribute("visible","true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with visible="false" is that the element behind it will not be clickable (because the element is there, but is transparent). So, the alternative I found is to make it with zero width.
Here is how I hide the element on mouse click:

```
document.getElementById("my_element_id").addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  document.getElementById("my_element_id").setAttribute("width", "0");
});
```

Comment: Most A-Frame entities don't have a width attribute.  Only a few (such as <a-box> do.

You can solve the issues about what is / is not clickable by appropriate settings on the raycaster object.

I wonder whether your answer is really applicable to A-Frame entities, or if you had 2D DOM elements in mind with this suggestion?