# How do I hide an aframe object using localStorage and the 'visible' attribute?

Tags: html, storage, hide, aframe

I would like to hide an aframe object using localStorage that is being called onto the HTML code, by manipulating the "visible" attribute.

I've looked through other articles like [How can I hide an element with A-Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210403/how-can-i-hide-an-element-with-a-frame)

but it does not work for me.

The following is my code:

```
  <a-obj-model
  visible = "localStorage.getItem('carVisibility')";
   id="carA"  src="#car_obj" mtl="#car_mtl" position="1 1 7" rotation="0 0 0"></a-obj-model>
```

My carVisibility localStorage is set as "false" and "true", depending on user's input.
If I replace the localStorage part with "visible = false;" it works perfectly. However, once I add the localStorage portion, it doesn't seem to connect and work. It's clear it's a syntax error, however, I'm not sure what's wrong with it?

Comment: You can't just add JavaScript code into HTML attributes. Best answer is Piotr's with the component.

Answer (score 1):

The `visible: ...` expects a `true` or `false` value. You can't place there js code, like `visible="1 === 2"`. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/07mwratx/1/).

You should place your logic in an aframe component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    // provided carVisibility is true or false
    this.el.setAttribute("visible", localStorage.getItem('carVisibility'))
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
<a-entity foo></a-entity>
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/07mwratx/3/). Set the `localStorage` to `true` or `false`, start and restart the fiddle (to make sure the local storage is set).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure value ="localStorage............" Is not being treated as string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carA').attr('visible', localStorage.getItem('carVisibility'));
});
```

Comment: Favor Piotr's answer as this requires jQuery, and running A-Frame code outside of components is not recommended.